# Wait for a setTimeout() to finish to continue processing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to loop through an array reading each element after some time, the only solution I've seen is to use setTimeOut() in Typescript.

The problem is that I need the function to finish to continue the process.

This is what I currently have:

```js
async function testData() {

  let arrT = ['data1','data2','data3']
  let countReq = 0
  let result = []
  for await (let getA of arrT) {

    countReq++
    setTimeout(async() => {
      result.push(
        `test - ${getA}`
      )
    }, countReq * 1000)

  }

  console.log(result)
  return result;

}
testData()
```

Now it returns the empty array because the process has not finished, I need to wait and return the array with the complete information

I don't know if using setTimeout() in this case is the best option, I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Wrap the setTimeout in a promise which you can await.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Promise` to resolve the task with `await`. You don't need to provide `await` after your `for` key.

```js
function sleepTimeout(interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, interval);
  });
};

async function testData() {

  let arrT = ['data1','data2','data3']
  let countReq = 0
  let result = []
  for (let getA of arrT) {
    countReq++

    await sleepTimeout(1000);
    
    result.push(`test - ${getA}`);
  }

  console.log(result)
  return result;

}
testData()
```

Comment: I had not tried with promise, I thought that the setTimeOut could do it alone. I need to multiply it by 1000 because if it takes less time the process breaks